# Import recorded genotype table in genlight object

Tags: r

I am trying to clean up my snp data by filter out any alleles that have depth < 3 and if the total depth of the locus is < 5 then exclude the genotype altogether i.e. turn into NA. Then I tried to record the "clean" genotypes back into genlight object. This is where I stuck.

**Recall genotypes based on the new depth filter**

```
het <- Map(function(x, y) x>0 & y>0, read.depth.ref.filter, read.depth.snp.filter)
hom_0 <- Map(function(x, y) x>0 & y==0, read.depth.ref.filter, read.depth.snp.filter)
hom_2 <- Map(function(x, y) x==0 & y>0, read.depth.ref.filter, read.depth.snp.filter)

re.geno <- read.depth.snp.filter
```

**Record the genotype table**

```
re.geno[] <- Map(ifelse, het, 1, re.geno)
re.geno[] <- Map(ifelse, hom_0, 0, re.geno)
re.geno[] <- Map(ifelse, hom_2, 2, re.geno)
```

I tried:

```
gl[,] <- t(re.geno[,])
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

R.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

I got my own answer which is

```
gl <- as.genlight(t(re.geno))
```